# Nativescript - Add textview to layout when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, xml, nativescript

So right now I have a text field with a button (add+) below it.

I would like to make it so every time text is entered into the Text Field, and the Add button is pressed, a new text view is added to a vertical layout below it with the text that the user typed in the field.

I do not want to simply make a text view invisible, then visible when clicked, because I would like them to be able to add more than one text view with whatever text they type.

Comment: What have you tried ? Do you have a specific error ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically add view in page or layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30548991/how-to-dynamically-add-view-in-page-or-layout). Label or Button or TextField, the logic is same. Just create the instance and add to your layout.